# GMF add a button to its toolbar

Tags: eclipse, button, user-interface, toolbar, eclipse-gmf

So I have a GMF editor that I'm doing some stuff there. When I'm using the GMF editor a toolbar is provided by the GMF (right above the editor).

How can I add a button to that toolbar? (not to the menu!)

Only things that I found until now and seems to be helpful are:
[delete some buttons from the toolbar](https://code.google.com/p/gmftools/wiki/DiagramActionBarContributor) and [GMF tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Integrating-EMF-GMF-Editors/index.html).

But somewhere in the middle I get lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found something useful in this pdf: [link](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ip/resources/GEF/GEF_Tutorial_2up.pdf) (chapter 9 - adding a custom action)  At least is a nice start.

Answer (score 0):

Use the org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.ui.services.action.contributionItemProviders extension point.
You'll find documentation in the description. Here you can contribute to GMF's toolbar using the toolbar path